# Laravel model method with default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There are two tables

- products
- pictures ( has product_id , priority)

In my **Product model** I can get all pictures with:

```
public function pictures(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Picture');
}
```

Now i want to create a **method in product** to get the main pictures url (lowest priority value with product_id of picture), and if there is no result return a default value. I tried:

```
public function mainpicture(){
    $picture = $this->pictures()->orderBy('priority','desc')->first();
    if($picture == null)
        return 'default/default.png';
    return $picture->url;
}
```

This gives the error:

> Relationship method must return an object of type
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

When returning a value it's never of the type  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation but just an url.
How can I make a method to get the mainpicture or a default value?

*The reason I want to create this function is: because I need it in alot of views and don't want to paste the same code in every view. 
Currently in all the views where I need the mainpicture I use:*

```
@if(isset($product->pictures[0]))
    {!! Html::image('/images/product/'.$product->id.'/thumb/'.pictures[0]->url, 'Product image', array('class'=> ' img-responsive')) !!}
@else
    {!! Html::image('/images/product/default/default.png', 'No picture found', array('class'=> ' img-responsive')) !!}
@endif
```

*This is very spaghetti like and a function would be much better.*

I could create a global helper function, but im curious if i could add it to my model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you already have a working solution by Kota. But may I suggest an alternative approach:

In Laravel you can define custom logic for fetching attributes.

They are defined like this:

```
public function getCustomAttribute() 
{
     return 'foo';
}
```

So in your case:

```
public function getMainpictureAttribute()
{
    $picture = $this->pictures()->orderBy('priority')->first();
    return ($picture) ? $picture->url : 'default/path.jpg';
}
```

In your view you now can access it with `$product->mainpicture`

Now how clean is that? And your saving an additional query for each product.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use [Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes). For example:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function scopeMainpicture($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('priority','desc');
    }

}
```

Then in the controller, you can use this as:

```
$main_picture_url = $product->mainpicture()->first()->url;

//send it to the view
return ('myview').with('main_picture_url',$main_picture_url);
```

Then in the view, just do this:

```
{{!! $main_picture_url !!}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem would be than that i need to add it to every controller function for the view where i need it, it would be much easyer if i could call $product->mainpicture in the views where i need it.

Comment: you can call $product->mainpicture . try it

Comment: I've added it to my view like  {!! $product->mainpicture->url !!}  i get an error 'Trying to get property of non-object'  also i still wouldn't have a default value if there is no result.

Comment: you should not do this in the view. Just send a final $main_picture_url from the controller into the view. See my edited answer

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i went with Kóta Péter's  solutions. in that way i dont need to add anything to the controllers.

Comment: sure np. But just a word of caution. You should ideally not do any calculations in the view. The view should just take data from the controller and display. Otherwise now you have to manage the calculations in both controller AND the view. Just something to think about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92582/discussion-between-sven-b-and-codegeek).